# Programmatically create gitlab-ci.yml file?

Tags: configuration, generator, gitlab-ci, dsl

Is there any tool to generate `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like Jenkins has job-dsl-plugin to create jobs?

[Jenkins DSL plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) allows me to generate jobs using `Groovy`, which outputs an `xml` that describes a job for Jenkins.

I can use DSL and a `json` file to generate jobs in Jenkins. What I’m looking for is a tool to help me generate `.gitlab-ci.yml` based on a specification.

Comment: I didn't go for a DSL like generator, but I wrote a generator that uses a jinja template to generate `.gitlab-ci.yml`. This allows me to specify which docker image I want to build from a huge list. [It can be found here](https://gitlab.com/gableroux/unity3d/tree/de673dc4/ci-generator). All I do is go to the generator folder, generate the file which also inject a comment telling people to not edit the file manually and then I commit the generated `.gitlab-ci.yml` to the project. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it may inspire some people. ✌

Answer (score 4):

The main question i have to ask what is your goal?

### just reduce maintenance effort for repeating job snippets:

Sometimes `.gitlab-ci.yml` file are pretty similar in a lot of projects, and you want to manage them centrally. Then i recommend to take a look at [Having Gitlab Projects calling the same gitlab-ci.yml stored in a central location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856638/having-gitlab-projects-calling-the-same-gitlab-ci-yml-stored-in-a-central-locati/65862929#65862929) - which shows multiple ways of centralizing your build,

### generate pipeline configuration as the build is highly flexible

Actually this is more a templating task, and can be achieved in nearly every script language you like.

With simple bash, groovy, python, go, .. you name it. In the end the question is, what kind of flexibility you strive for, and what kind of logic you need for the generation. I will not go into the detail on how to generate a the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, but how to use it for your next step. Because this is in my opinion the most crucial step. There is the way of simply generating and committing it, but you can also use GitLab CI to generate a file for you, which will be used in the next job of your pipeline.

```yaml
setup:
  script:
    - echo ".." # generate your yaml file here, maybe use a custom image
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated.gitlab-ci.yml

trigger:
  needs:
    - setup
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated.gitlab-ci.yml
        job: setup
    strategy: depend
```

This allows you to generate a child pipeline and execute it - we use this for highly generic builds in monorepos.

see for further reading

- [GitLab JSONNET Example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/project-templates/jsonnet/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) - documentation example for generated yml files within a pipeline
- [Dynamic Childpipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) - documentation for dynamically created pipelines