# Having Gitlab Projects calling the same gitlab-ci.yml stored in a central location

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have many Gitlab project followed the same CI template. Whenever there is a small change in the CI script, I have to manually modify the CI script in each project. Is there a way you can store your CI script in a central location and have your project called that CI script with some environment variable substitution? For instance,

gitlab-ci.yml in each project

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL <link_to_the_central_location>.sh)"
```

gitlab-ci.yml in the central location

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build-code-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Check the ruby version, then build some Ruby project files:"
    - ruby -v
    - rake

test-code-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "If the files are built successfully, test some files with one command:"
    - rake test1

test-code-job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "If the files are built successfully, test other files with a different command:"
    - rake test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need curl, actually gitlab supports this via the include directive.

1. you need a repository, where you store your general yml files. (you can choose if it is a whole ci file, or just parts. For this example lets call this repository CI and assume your gitlab runs at example.com - so the project url would be example.com/ci. we create two files in there just to show the possibilities.

   1. is a whole CI definition, ready to use - lets call the file `ci.yml`. This approach is not really flexible

      ```
       stages:
         - build
         - test

       build-code-job:
         stage: build
         script:
           - echo "Check the ruby version, then build some Ruby project files:"
           - ruby -v
           - rake

       test-code-job1:
         stage: test
         script:
           - echo "If the files are built successfully, test some files with one command:"
           - rake test1

       test-code-job2:
         stage: test
         script:
           - echo "If the files are built successfully, test other files with a different command:"
           - rake test2
      ```
   2. is a partly CI definition, which is more extendable. lets call the files `includes.yml`

      ```
       .build:
         stage: build
         script:
           - echo "Check the ruby version, then build some Ruby project files:"
           - ruby -v
           - rake

       .test:
         stage: test
         script:
           - echo "this script tag will be overwritten"
      ```
   3. There is even the option to use template string from yaml. please reference the gitlab documentation but it is similar to 2.
2. we do have our project which wants to use such definitions. so either

   1. For the whole CI file

      ```
       include:
         - project: 'ci'
           ref: master # think about tagging if you need it
           file: 'ci.yml'
      ```

      as you can see now we are referencing one yml file, with all the cahnges.
   2. with partial extends

      ```
       include:
         - project: 'ci'
           ref: master # think about tagging if you need it
           file: 'includes.yml'

       stages:
         - build
         - test

       build-code-job:
         extends: .build

       job1:
         extends: .test
         script:
           - rake test1

       job2:
         extends: .test
         script:
           - rake test2
      ```

      As you see, you can easily use the includes, to have a way more granular setup. Additionally you could define at `job1` and `job2` variables, eg for the test target, and move the script block into the `includes.yml`

Futhermore you can also use [anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#yaml-anchors-for-scripts) for the script parts. Which looks like this

includes.yml

```
.build-scirpt: &build
     - echo "Check the ruby version, then build some Ruby project files:"
     - ruby -v
     - rake

.build:
   stage: build
   script:
     - *build
```

and you can use also the script anchor within your configuration

For a deeper explanation you can also take a look at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html

Comment: Thank you! The explanation is really helpful!

Comment: My only worry about having a centralised script is that if there's an error in the script all the other gitlab projects that are referring to this script will have trouble deploying, is there a version control feature for the central ci yaml so that you can specify maybe in project A you are using version #1 of the central yaml while B is using version #2 of that?

Comment: you do see the `ref:master` which references the master branch - you can always think about tagging your centralized ci yaml. or even using different branches for that. - so even if something changes, you only have to change a tag version in the other scripts

Comment: Thanks. From the documentation, it stated that "The merging lets you extend and override dictionary mappings, but you cannot add or modify items to an included array. For example, to add an additional item to the production job script, you must repeat the existing script items", but I saw in your partial extends script you have add the "rake test1" command right after you extend the command(echo) from the includes.yml?