# How to create a common pipeline in GitLab for many similar projects

Tags: gitlab, teamcity, gitlab-ci

We have hundreds of similar projects in GitLab which have the same structure inside.

To build these projects we use a one common TeamCity build. We trigger and pass project GitLab URL along with other parameters to the build via API, so TeamCity build knows which exact project needs to be fetched/cloned. TeamCity VCS root accepts target URL via parameter.

The question is how to replace existing TeamCity build with a GitLab pipeline.

I see the general approach is to have CI/CD configuration file(.gitlab-ci.yml) directly in project. Since the structure of the projects the same this is not the option to duplicate the same CI/CD config file across all projects.

I'm wondering is it possible to create a common pipeline for several projects which can accept the target project URL via parameter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the full CICD config in a repository and put in all your projects a simple  .gitlab-ci.yml which includes the shared file.

With thus approach there is no redundant definition of the jobs.

Still, you can add specific other jobs to specific projects (in the regarding .gitlab-ci.yml files or define variables in a problem and use [some jobs conditionally](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)) - you can also include multiple other definition files, e.g. if you have multiple similar projects.

cf. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include

With latest GitLab (13.9) there are even more referencing methods possible: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#reference-tags

Answer (score 0):

As @MrTux already pointed out, you can use [includes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include).

You can either use it to include a whole CI file, or to include just certain steps. in [Having Gitlab Projects calling the same gitlab-ci.yml stored in a central location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856638/having-gitlab-projects-calling-the-same-gitlab-ci-yml-stored-in-a-central-locati/) - you can find detailed explanation with examples of both usages

Comment: i am not sure, if this would be sufficient as just a comment to @mrTux example, but i think it is crucial information, so i put it for now as an own Answer - if this is bad practice let me know, than i will add it as a comment to the other anwer